# CoreData not returning updated values

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm working with some existing code that interacts with CoreData. I made some changes that I later realized introduced a regression. I was able to isolate the lines of code that introduced the problem, but I cannot for the life of me understand why it's an issue at all.

The code involves reading articles and marking them as read. I didn't make any changes to the marking code and determined that still functions correctly. However, in another layer of the code that's getting the list of read articles, I made the following change:

```
//Old
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    ...
    [self retrieveReadArticles];
    ...
}

- (void)retrieveReadArticles {
    userHistory = [UserHistory retrieveUserHistory]; //stored in iVar
    self.readArticles = userHistory.readArticles;
}
```

The above works fine, and gives me an updated list of read articles.

```
//New
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    ...
    [self retrieveReadArticles];
    ...
}

- (void)retrieveReadArticles {
    UserHistory* userHistory = [UserHistory retrieveUserHistory]; //local variable
    self.readArticles = userHistory.readArticles;
}
```

This change in scope breaks the functionality, and causes the list of read articles to never update.

A colleague and I were speculating that the ivar allows the operation to complete fully, while the local variable must not be retained properly and goes out of scope before it can return updates. Can anyone point me toward a resource that explains this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the marking code may have been the problem after all. We were retrieving a dictionary of existing read articles, adding another entry to it, and saving the `UserHistory` object again. Changing that code to create a brand new dictionary with the existing read articles appears to solve the problem without needing to use ivar scope.